# custom error message instead of FATAL ERROR in Wordpress plugin activation if WooCommerce is not acive

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am trying to give a graceful custom message upon activation of the plugin, if Woocommerce is not activated.

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
```

The above express is to check whether Woocommerce is active and if it returns false, I do not want the plugin to be activated and wants to throw a custom error. I have tried to stop execution with `die()` and `trigger_error`. In these cases, it shows a `FATAL ERROR`.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Nothing in the above code should be triggering a fatal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`deactivate_plugins`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/deactivate_plugins) function . Try this:

```
class MyPlugin {

        public function __construct() {
                register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this , 'activate' ) );
        }

        public function activate() {

                // Check if Woo is active
                if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

                        // Woo is active.

                } else {

                        deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
                        wp_die( __( 'Please activate WooCommerce.', 'my-plugin' ), 'Plugin dependency check', array( 'back_link' => true ) );

                }

                // Do activate Stuff now.
        }
}

new MyPlugin();
```

Comment: I am looking for the code that deals with "error_scapes" to handle this situation. This code is taking us to another big page with the error message in it. I would prefer showing error message on that plugin activation page it self.

Comment: There's no way of achieving what you are trying to. Unless you stop the plugin activation, there's nothing stopping it from being activated. Once a hook is fired, in this case `register_activation_hook` there's no way of halting its execution without `wp_die` or `exit`.  You could use `header('location:/wp-admin/plugins.php` which is the same as stopping the execution.

Comment: I have some requirement. Can you contact me at go4buck [at] yahoo com ?

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is throw and admin notice if WooCommerce isn't available. And then just stop the running of your plugin.

```
if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ){
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'so_32551934_woocommerce_warning' );
    return; // STOP THE WHOLE PLUGIN
}

function so_32551934_woocommerce_warning(){ ?>
    <div class="error">
        <p><?php _e( 'Whoa, you\'re gonna need WooCommerce to run my fancy plugin!', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
   <?php 
}

// The rest of your plugin follows here
```

Any code that you put here at the end will be run as long as WooCommerce is active. Note, I didn't test this so be careful of typos.

Comment: This code is not working though I have fixed few syntax errors. I am looking for the code that deals with "error_scapes" to handle this situation.

Comment: What is an "error_scape"? My code should have said `! in_array()` instead of `in_array()`. Typo on my part. I just tested it on a plugin I am developing and it halts the plugin and displays an error notice.

Comment: @helgatheviking, does the code stop the plugin from getting activated? If yes, can you please paste some more code, would be nice to learn something new. OP doesn't want his plugin to activate if WooCommerce is deactivated.

Comment: No it doesn't prevent the plugin from activating. It prevents the important parts of the plugin from running which is more or less the same thing, with the added benefit of displaying an admin notice so the users know *why* the plugin isn't working without panicking everyone with a `wp_die()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```
    class FT_AdminNotice {

       /**
       * Register the activation hook
       */
       public function __construct() {
          register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'ft_install' ) );
       }

      /**
      * Deactivate the plugin and display a notice if the dependent plugin is not active.
      */
      public function ft_install() {
          if ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) 
          {
               $this->ft_deactivate_plugin();
               wp_die( sprintf(__( 'This plugin requires Woocommerce to be installed and activated.', 'domain-text' ) ) );
          }
      }

      /**
      * Function to deactivate the plugin
      */
      protected function ft_deactivate_plugin() {
           require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
           deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
           if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) {
                 unset( $_GET['activate'] );
           }
      }

   }

   new FT_AdminNotice();
```

This way show message and you can enrich it like explain [here](https://fluentthemes.com/best-way-to-abort-a-plugin-and-show-admin-notice-when-dependent-plugins-minimum-version-is-not-met/) and stop execution too.